# unexpected token output json file using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
const targetFolder = './app/images/';
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

let json = [];
fs.readdir(targetFolder , (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({file.split('.')[0]})
  });
})

jsonfile.writeFile(targetFolder , json);
```

It is strange when json.push doesn't work here. When I do console like

```
console.log(file.split('.')[0]) I can see the list of files in my terminal.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an unexpected token error because there's an unexpected token:

```
json.push({file.split('.')[0]})
// Here -------^
```

An object initializer consists of key/value pairs. In ES2015+, if we're getting the value from a variable, we can just include the variable and the key will be inferred from the variable name, but you can't do that with any arbitrary expression.

So for instance, if you want the object's key to be `foo`:

```
json.push({foo: file.split('.')[0]});
```

Or if you didn't want an object at all, just the value, remove the `{}`:

```
json.push(file.split('.')[0]);
```

---

The **next** problem, once you fix the `json.push` call, is that no calls to `json.push` will be made before your `writeFile` call is made, because `readdir` calls its callback *asynchronously*. More: [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
json.push({file.split('.')[0]})
```

to

```
json.push({'fileName': file.split('.')[0]})
```

and

you are using async code as sync code.
in your your file is written way before your readdir is executed.

the correct way to do it is as follows.

```
const targetFolder = './app/images/';
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

let json = [];
fs.readdir(targetFolder , (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({'fileName': file.split('.')[0]})
  });
  jsonfile.writeFile(targetFolder , json);
})
```

or if you want to so it in sync  the do it as follows

```
const targetFolder = './app/images/';
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

let json = [];
let files = fs.readdirSync(targetFolder);

files.forEach(file => {
    json.push({'fileName': file.split('.')[0]})
});

jsonfile.writeFile(targetFolder ,json);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted, this is only part of the issue. It still has invalid syntax in: `json.push({file.split('.')[0]})`

Comment: readdirSync error : TypeError: "options" must be a string or an object

Comment: @Mellisa, sorry about that, edited the code, will work now.